# How to pass as json data to entity in php

Tags: php, json, object

I have a json file something like this:

```
"partners": {
            "201": {
                "name": "Good Partner",
                "url": "http://www.foo.com",
                "rating": 2,
                "prices": {
                    "2001": {
                        "description": "Gizzy Wiggy Tom",
                        "amount": 52,
                        "from": "2012-10-12",
                        "to": "2012-10-13"
                    },
                    "2002": {
                        "description": "Lambambacam",
                        "amount": 502,
                        "from": "2012-10-12",
                        "to": "2012-10-13"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and I have Partner entities like:

```
class Partner implements PartnerInterface {
/**
 * Name of the partner
 * 
 * @var string
 */
public $sName;

/**
 * Url of the partner's homepage (root link)
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $sHomepage;

/**
 * Unsorted list of prices received from the
 * actual search query.
 *
 * @var Price[]
 */
public $aPrices = array ();

/**
 *
 * @var Validation Obj
 */
private $oValidation;

/**
 *
 * @param ValidationInterface $iValidator           
 */
public function __construct(ValidationInterface $iValidator) {
    $this->oValidator = $iValidator;
}

/**
 * This method checks if the provided url is valid or not.
 * 
 * @see ...\Entity\PartnerInterface::validatePartnerHomepage()
 */
public function validatePartnerHomepage() {
    if ($this->oValidator->isValideUrl ( $this->sHomepage )) {
        return;
    } else {
        return $this->oValidator->aValidationErrors = array(
            'url' =>$this->sHomepage,
            'message' => 'The url is not valid'
        );
    }
}}
```

And Price Entity:

```
class Price implements PriceInterface{
 /**
 * Description text for the rate/price
 * 
 * @var string
 */
public $sDescription;

/**
 * Price in dollars
 * 
 * @var float
 */
public $fAmount;

/**
 * Arrival date, represented by a DateTime obj
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 */
public $oFromDate;

/**
 * Departure date, represented by a DateTime obj
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 */
public $oToDate;}
```

Now I want to pass the values to this entities after reading the json file. Can any one suggest me the best way to traverse through this data and map to the entities and maybe later persist to database or return to the front-end after validation.

The basic idea here is I curl to a web service and get the data. I have my entities and want to pass the data to my entities and later add to my database.

Answer (score 0):

If you rename all your JSON fields name into the same as your classes one, or the classes one into the JSON field names, you could do as such (It's a draft, so they may be errors):

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$partners = array();

foreach($data["partners"] as $partner)
{
    $prices_pre = $partner["prices"];
    $class = new Partner();
    unset($partner["prices"]);
    foreach ($data AS $key => $value) $class->{$key} = $value;
    $prices = array();
    foreach($prices_pre as $price)
    {
        $price_class = new Price();
        foreach ($data AS $key => $value) $price_class->{$key} = $value;
        $prices[] = $price_class;
    }
    $partners[] = $class;
}
?>
```